# Copy to multiple destinations with Windows 7 (no third party software)

Tags: powershell, directory, copy

I need to copy several subdirectories to several higher level directories.

eg. I want to create directories `{ "t1","t2","t3"}` in the folders `C:\User\Tim` ; `C:\User\Bob` etc.

So the result should be:
`c:\User\Bob\t1` ; `c:\User\Bob\t2` ; `c:\User\Bob\t3` (and the same for Tim).

Is there a way to easily do this (instead of copying them all one by one?). The reason therefore is that I have more than 1000 different folders to copy/create.

I'm working on a win7 and there is no possibility to download any third party software (because I'm doing this at work).

Apparently PowerShell could help, but I can't find the correct command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just create two arrays:

- one that defines the subfolders to create
- one that defines the destination folders

Then you have to iterate over both arrays and use the `md` command to create the folder:

```
$subfoldersToCreate = @('t1', 't2', 't3')
$destinationFolders = @('c:\Users\Tim', 'c:\Users\Bob')

foreach ($desination in $destinationFolders)
{
    $subfoldersToCreate | Foreach-Object {
        md (Join-Path $desination $_)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Any idea how I can easily copy the destination folders? So instead of typing all destination folders by hand, have them all in one list by command/other. This because their are more than 1000 destination folders (Tim, Bob, Micky, Alex, etc).


Thanks a bunch for the quick response

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you have a file containing the usernames and want to use this to create the destination folders?

Comment: I just have a lot of destination folders. 

Let me explain with an example:
We have the master directory c:\user . In this directory there are al lot of users, so c:\user\Tim ; c:\user\Bob; c:\user\Alex etc etc.

What I need is a document where I can quickly copy/paste these paths so I can easily paste them in the code you provided.

My question to you is if you know there is such a way to do this, as this will spare me a lot of time.

Comment: Try this: `(Get-ChildItem (Split-Path $env:USERPROFILE) -Directory | 
    Where Name -NotMatch '^\.NET' | 
    Foreach {"'$($_.FullName)'"}) -join ','` . This script gets all user folders, wrap them with single quotes und join them by a comma. You can append `| clip` to the code and you have all users ready to paste in your clipboard